# Mathematica.SE Blog

Tags: discussion

I might have been too eager with this. Let's start slowly ;)

**Are we interested in having our own blog?**

**What content do we want to share in our blog?**

Comment: I don't want to belittle your enthusiasm. I think it's great that you thought of this. But the existing official blogoverflow approach will work better. It is just a matter of picking a time to start it and making sure we have good content lined up.

Comment: Sure, I have no problem with hosting this on BlogOverflow. I'm just concerned that discussion is about choosing a particular host, rather than on the more important questions like "Do we really want a blog?" or "What goes into the blog?".

Comment: Fair enough - I think there was a discussion earlier (maybe on chat) that we would definitely have a blog once we had critical mass. But we needed to make sure that there were enough possible contributors to avoid burning out our highest-rep users.

Answer (score 9):

> I've wanted to share code more than once, but it doesn't really fit in the stack. The blog would serve such a purpose: I don't really have a question, I just want to share what I've done and how I've done it

I think what you're looking for is a *personal* blog...

As F'x notes, there are mechanisms in place to set up a blog associated with this site. However, we also need committed users to provide quality content on a regular basis. Right now, everyone is busy nurturing a community here that extends beyond the coterie on StackOverflow and MathGroup. Once everyone has found their rhythm, we can get contributors to write articles on a regular basis.

However, I *don't* think the blog should be a place for sharing every little snippet of code that someone found interesting or managed to write; it should be interesting to wide audience. I don't mean to stomp on your eagerness, but a blog for the site doesn't necessarily mean all users can post whenever they want, like a tweet. Certainly, any user can contribute, but in all probability, there's going to be an editorial team which will be responsible for the content.

Comment: Very well put! I would add to that, that my subjective feeling is that the time for it did not come yet. Coming out of Beta might be a good time to start it. Generally, I think that the time for that will come when we get much fatter tails in our user rep distribution, than we have now, so that everything would not depend so crucially on a small number of power users (a better metric perhaps would be not rep but a number of users as a function of a number of accepted answers).

Answer (score 6):

The StackExchange network already provides a framework for its sites’ communities to create and maintain [blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs): see for example [English](http://english.blogoverflow.com/), [Gaming](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Apple](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/), even some beta sites like [Fitness](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/).

I believe there is no real need to maintain a separate blog. But, if the need were to arise, we should ask the team to set up a blogoverflow for us!

Comment: @Fx I know. But note that all of these sites are launched, and we're in beta. Also, looking at their guidelines for getting a blog, I think this post qualifies as pertinent.

Comment: @CHM my point stands, I believe. You propose a solution, but what is the need it fills?

Comment: @CHM also, there are beta sites in the list; I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I've wanted to share code more than once, but it doesn't really fit in the stack. The blog would serve such a purpose: _I don't really have a question, I just want to share what I've done and how I've done it_

Comment: @Fx I guess the main difference between going for a BlogOverflow or a Blogger is that, with the latter we have total control of our blog, whereas if we get an SE blog, we won't. If ever we lose interest in the blog, it's no big deal. And if the blog is very lively and well, then we can move it to BlogOverflow, once we're launched.

Comment: @chm Not sure what kind of control you would be missing at blog-overflow. A blogger/gmail affair would depend too much on one user, the owner of the accounts, which would make it a bit too vulnerable to my tastes.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The blog is set up with a master account, but anybody who wants can contribute. With a Blogger, we wouldn't have guidelines to follow other than our own, deliberated in the meta. But I think the point is whether we want a blog, not where we should host it. I wouldn't mind having a BlogOverflow, as long as everyone can write posts (of a certain quality, of course) on what they want, when they want.