# What happened to the idea of implementing a community blog?

Tags: discussion

I wonder what happened to the idea of [our own community blog](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/a-blog-for-mathematica-se-volunteers-suggestions-for-post-topics/421#421). Several volunteers had agreed to provide good content.

The discussion was promising, and I wonder if anything had come out of it because all I can find right now is the "Page not found ... Panda" when looking for the blog.

Comment: I guess the appropriate way would be to simply comment under the original question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you should notice that StackExchange has discontinued all blogs and [will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow). The biggest problem was that most blogs, our blog included, were not active.

The reason for that is most likely that people are busy. I barely make it to 4 blog-posts per year on my own site; not because I couldn't think of interesting topics, but because there are so many other things to do. Additionally, a good part of the people who commented on this original idea are no longer active (or as active as they were). This includes rm, Leonid, Mr.Wizard, Istvan, Heike, Verbeia, and Rojo.

Many of us have their own blog but as Kuba commented, it is worth mentioning that C.E. has set up

- [wolframlanguagereviews.org](http://wolframlanguagereviews.org/)

Comment: Worth to mention a ready to use alternative by C.E.: http://wolframlanguagereviews.org/